# Does $Re\left( \int_{\gamma} f \right) = \int_{\gamma} Re(f)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently studying complex analysis. My current thinking is as follows:

Let $f(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$. By definition, $$\int_{\gamma} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{a}^{b} f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$
and so by substitution, $$\int_{\gamma} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{a}^{b}x(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t + i \int_{a}^{b} y(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.$$
Thus, $$Re\left( \int_{\gamma} f \right) =\int_{a}^{b}x(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.$$
Now, $$\int_{\gamma} Re(f(t))\, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{\gamma}x(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{a}^{b} x(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.$$
We see that these expressions are indeed the same, and so $Re\left( \int_{\gamma} f \right) = \int_{\gamma} Re(f)$. This seems so straightforward, and I've been trying for ages to come up with a counter example, but I haven't been able to find one. What are your thoughts?

Comment: The notation $\int_\gamma f$ can be a little misleading from a formal perspective.

Comment: Yes, you should really avoid writing $\int_{\gamma} f$. Usually in the context of complex analysis we are working with $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz$, but there are some situations where integrals such as $\int_\gamma f(z)\,|dz|$ also pop up.

Answer (score 6):

This is not true. Take for example $\gamma$ as the unit circle and $f(z) = z$.

Then $\int_\gamma z\,dz = 0$, but
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma x\,dz &= \frac12\left(\int_\gamma z\,dz + \int_\gamma \bar z\,dz\right)\\
&= 0 + \frac12 \int_\gamma \frac{\bar z z}{z}\,dz \\
&= \frac12 \int_\gamma \frac{1}{z}\,dz = \pi i.
\end{align}

Comment: Great counter example! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No: Define $f(x + iy) = iy$, and $\gamma$ is the line segment connecting $0$ and $i$. Then

$$\int_{\gamma} f = \int_0^1 (it) (i dt) = -\frac 1 2$$

On the other hand, $\Re{f} = 0$.

---

The flaw in the proof is that $\gamma'(t)$ need not be real.

Comment: Of course! $y'(t)$ need not be real, totally missed that. Owww... Thank you!